# jquery regex .replace not writing to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I'm trying to normalize/clean up the formatting inside content:

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Type your entry">

    <p>djsalk fjsadlkjf sadfjlsadkfj</p>
    <p> </p>
    <div>laksdfj asdlkasdf&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

with the following js:

```
$('.content').html().replace(/\/div/g , '<p>');
$('.content').html().replace(/\/div/g , '</p>');
$('.content').html().replace('<p> </p>', '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pNzqY/

if I run each of these lines in the webinspector manually it returns the fixed string, but doesn't apply it to the dom then either.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Side note: `replace` is a native JavaScript function, not from jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The replace function generates a new string. You need to assign that new value back to the dom manually like this:

```
$('.content').html($('.content').html().replace(/\/div/g , '<p>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript strings are immutable and jQuery's `.html()` returns a string (not some reference to the elements actual html). You have to set the html after you modify that. A nice way to do this with jQuery is calling [`.html()` with a function and returning a value](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml):

```
$('.content').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/\/div/g , '<p>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pNzqY/1/

Comment: makes sense but when I inspect the html in the fiddle , it still doesn't appear changed. Also out of curiosity, what's the 'i' parameter referring to?

Comment: @Pirijan index of element in the jQuery object